# How to add a fade effect to a jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a fade in / fade out effect to a div that is created using jquery but I cant seem to figure it out. Any ideas ?

Heres my current code :

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('hintOnce') !== 'true') {
        $('body').append('<div class="control-hint"><p> Use the controls to improve your browsing experience. </p><div class="close">X</div></div>')
        sessionStorage.setItem('hintOnce','true');
        }

        $('.control-hint').on('click',function(){
        $('.control-hint').hide();
      });
```

Thanks in advance,

Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in jq object then hide it before fading it in:

```
$('body').append($('<div class="control-hint"><p> Use the controls to improve your browsing experience. </p><div class="close">X</div></div>').hide().fadeIn());
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Ad inline style `display: none` to your div. Then just select it and call `fadeOut` on it.

```
$('body').append('<div class="control-hint" style="display: none"><p> Use the controls to improve your browsing experience. </p><div class="close">X</div></div>');
$('.control-hint').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :

```
$('<div class="control-hint"><p> Use the controls to improve your browsing experience. </p><div class="close">X</div></div>').appendTo("body").hide().fadeIn(300);
```